# Python - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '15.5'

Tags: python, average

```
primera_nota = raw_input("Dame tu primera nota: ")
segunda_nota = raw_input("Dame tu segunda nota: ")
tercera_nota = raw_input("Dame tu tercera nota: ")
cuarta_nota = raw_input("Dame tu cuarta nota: ")

arreglo = [primera_nota, segunda_nota, tercera_nota, cuarta_nota]

suma_calificaciones = 0

for total in range(len(arreglo)):
    suma_calificaciones = suma_calificaciones + int(str(arreglo[total]))

promedio = float(suma_calificaciones) / len(arreglo)

print "El total de tus calificaciones es:", promedio
```

The problem I have is that when the program asks me my notes and I input a decimal number, it raises an error.
The program runs well without putting on any decimal value, and if several notes eg 15-12 - 16-20 gives me 15.75 as it should be .

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the values to an `int` convert them to a `float` so you can do decimals. Also since `raw_input` already gives you the values as a `string` you can probably remove the `str()`.

```
suma_calificaciones = suma_calificaciones + float(arreglo[total])
```

Another thing you can improve is your for loop:

```
for val in arreglo:
    suma_calificaciones = suma_calificaciones + float(val)
```